# Can we create a React JS page inside an asp.net web application? (Not Core and MVC) A Basic Asp.net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I want to use a React page in an Asp.Net web application which is not an MVC nor Core.

Answer (score 1):

I not done this, but from what this states?

http://xabikos.com/2015/03/18/Using-Reactjs-net-in-Web-Forms/

It certainly looks like you can. I mean, it really mostly just a javascript framework, and thus such frameworks can be adopted quite much with any system that supports JavaScript. I have not delved into what server side code and how react code can be written to run server side. However, how to run such code server side js code was never clear to me anyway.

So, in general, you can adopt and inject react into your web forms project.

I not really sure I would want to do this, and I would think just a new fresh up of the webforms say using bootstrap classes would produce nice results, and introduction of react would probably only be a great idea if you starting from scratch anyway.

Comment: Thanks to Immediate Response Albert. I've referred this URL. But it shows how to integrate React with Asp.Net MVC. But my problem is, My project is a pure ASp.Net web application. It is not having MVC structure and It is not .Net core also.

Comment: It also references and notes webforms. Webforms thus does NOT mean MVC, and thus does NOT mean .net core. So that part of the article means even vb.net, and standard webforms - it is not only limited to MVC or .net core, but also is for standard .net and webforms.

Comment: Is that possible to implement react without an MVC controller?